# Delete all pending invitations to Organization in Github

Tags: api, github

I am trying to delete all pending invites to a organization. I cannot find an api which will delete all invitations or even delete a single invite.

I can find apis to list invites and create invites - [Github Invites](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/orgs#create-an-organization-invitation)

Even this [question](https://github.community/t/cancelling-an-organization-invitation-rest-api/127019) asked before on support doesn't have a clear answer.

Some of the users are already part of the organization but have pending invites, so if I use the remove user from organization this may delete the invite also and will also remove the user.

Comment: I think the invitations expires automatically in 7 days. not sure about deleting the invite before that.

Comment: For my organization at least the invitations haven't expired. Found a way to delete it from Github website itself though. UI is not very intuitive for it though.